# Open a Google Doc in a sidebar?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, sidebar

Is it possible to open a Google Doc in the sidebar of the UI? I want to be able to open a simple document to store userData for a Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant. Sidebar is htmlservice and uses caja which doesnt allow iframes.
You can however read ghe gdoc and display it as html on the sidebar and write your own edit functionality (as simple plain text)